# How can I formally and in a short way ask, "Have you passed through any surgery on your ass"?

Tags: american-english

It's for an online form. I must know if the person filling the form has a natural or operated ass. I need a short format. Currently we have: Do you have an operated ass? Is it okay this way? It doesn't need to be formal, but it must be clear and serious.

Comment: "Is that a real donkey or is it a robot?"

Comment: This is for real. I'm not a native speaker and I don't want to come off sounding like an ass 

Comment: “Do you have any derma fillers, or silicone implants in your body?” This covers their ass as well as yours.

Comment: Find a word other than "ass".

Comment: Nobody is going to take you seriously if you ask if you have an "operated a$$". If you are sincere, then use *buttocks*. Otherwise, I can imagine you will be facing a lawsuit or a hacking attempt.

Comment: I have one question for the ass and another for breasts. This one is good @Mari-LouA, thanks. Do you have any silicone implants in your butt? is fine I guess, but too big.

Comment: It's a NSFW page @FeliniusRex, I think the company will be fine. Is the word Buttocks commonly understandable?

Comment: The word "ass" is vulgar slang. If you use the word "ass," then the people that use your form will probably think that you are insulting them. (I think the word "ass" is also inappropriate for the title of a Stack Exchange question, usually. I think you should edit your question's title and change "ass" to "buttocks.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper expression would be [„buttock enhancement“](http://plasticsurgery.org), as in „Have you ever undergone buttock enhancement?“, or „have you had buttock enhancement lately?“